# JSON decode nested array PHP loop

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, nested

I know there are similar questions all over Stackoverflow, but I did not find any help for the problem I'm having.

I have this JSON:

```
[{
"name": "Name0",
"services": [
    [{
        "Service": "Service00",
        "Description": "Desc00"
    }, {
        "Service": "Service01",
        "Description": "Desc01"
    }]
]
}, {
"name": "Name1",
"services": [
    [{
        "Service": "Service10",
        "Description": "Desc10"
    }]
]
}]
```

I loop through it with:

```
$quoteJson = json_decode($quoteJson);

foreach($quoteJson as $mydata) {
    echo $mydata->name . "<br>";
        foreach($mydata->services as $key => $value)
            {
                echo $value[$key]->Service . "<br>";
                echo $value[$key]->Description . "<br>";
            }
 }
```

And the result I get is:

```
Name0
Service00
Desc00

Name1
Service10
Desc10
```

I am not able to loop through the service elements, to get:

```
Name0
Service00
Desc00
Service01
Desc01

Name1
Service10
Desc10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, `services` is an array in an array. Made a small change to your code:

```
foreach($quoteJson as $mydata) {                                                                                                  
    echo $mydata->name . "<br>";                                                                                                          
    foreach($mydata->services[0] as $key => $value)                                                                                       
    {                                                                                                                                     
        echo $value->Service . "<br>";                                                                                                    
        echo $value->Description . "<br>";                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                      
}
```

And now it it returns:

> Name0
> Service00
> Desc00
> Service01
> Desc01
> Name1
> Service10
> Desc10

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! Will make some resaerch as I don't understand why [0] index is needed.

Comment: Currently your `services` object contains a nested array. Essentially: `"services": [ [ ] ]`. You use the [0] to access the first, and only element in `services`, which contains the data you're trying to reach.

Answer (score 1):

Since $mydata->services is multi dimensional array, you need to loop $value variable.

```
$quoteJson = json_decode($quoteJson);

foreach($quoteJson as $mydata) {
    echo $mydata->name . "\n";

        foreach($mydata->services as $key => $value)
            {
                foreach($value as $k=>$v){ // loop the array
                    echo $v->Service . "\n";
                    echo $v->Description . "\n";
                }
            }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The output is not as expected  because you have missed  an inner loop.
the code below works fine.

```
foreach($quoteJson as $mydata) {
echo $mydata->name . "<br>";
    foreach($mydata->services as $key => $value)
    {
        foreach($value as $innerdata){
            echo $innerdata->Service . "<br>";
            echo $innerdata->Description . "<br>";
        }
    }
```

}